# How to call this php function

Tags: php, mysql, class

```
// Gets a single row from $from where $where is true    
    function Select($from, $where='', $orderBy='', $limit='', $like=false, $operand='AND',$cols='*'){
```

---

```
Let's say I created the object  - 
$oMySQL = new MySQL();

$oMySQL->Select();
```

### if I was doing  this query `- SELECT * FROM users where email='$email'"`

I can do insert and all the others - But I am confused how to make the `select();`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$oMySQL.Select('tbl', "tbl.field = 'value'", 'tbl.name', '0,25');`

Answer (score 1):

Since i do not know how the Select function is implemented i would assume something like this:

```
$oMySQL->Select('users', "email='$email'");
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape values that come from users. You can mysql_real_escape_string. Or end up using something like MySQL PDO or MySQLi since they allows for parametized expressions.

Comment: Yes that is right. I should have mentioned that. But since this looks like a framework method, i assumed that this is the case.